# Split multiselect

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a multi-select dropdown box which contains fields in a database table.

My question is how do I post the select fields as seperate variables?

For example, If someone selects `personID` and `email` from the multiselect box, how can i then use the below query to get the info from the DB (the select name is `field`)

```
$personID = $row ['personID'];
$email= $row ['email'];
```

Here is my select field

```
<div id="colDiv" style="display:none;">
<label class="">Select a Field</label>
  <select multiple="multiple" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Column" name="field" data-init-plugin="select2" id="colDropDown" >
    </select>
</div>
```

I hope this makes sense, I am a newbie and not sure how to word this one!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: with just html, you can't. you'd need JS to tear apart the `select` and build multiple key=value pairs for each selected item.

Comment: How do I do this? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="colDiv" style="display:none;">
<label class="">Select a Field</label>
  <select multiple="multiple" class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Column" name="field" data-init-plugin="select2" id="colDropDown" >
    </select>
</div>
```